# How to make a function's arguments' types follow another function's arguments'

Tags: typescript

```
type Func = (...args: any) => any;

// I use overwrite() to re-define an existing function
function overwrite(originalFunc: Func, newFunc: Func) {
  
}

function demo(str: string, num: number) {
  console.log(str, num);
}

// Re-define the demo() function
overwrite(demo, (str, num) {
  console.log('new func', str, num);
  demo(str, num);
});
```

As above, in TypeScript how to define the types in definition of overwrite() to make the *newFunc*'s arguments follow the *originalFunc*'s.

Answer (score 2):

Use generics to define a function type that both parameters share

```
function overwrite<F extends Function>(originalFunc: F, newFunc: F) {}

function demo(str: string, num: number) {
  console.log(str, num);
}

overwrite(demo, (a: string, b: number) => {});  // Fine
overwrite(demo, (a: number, b: string) => {});  // Error
```

Comment: Cool ! thanks. BTW, if I want to define a function after(), it is used like: after(demo, (originalResult, str, num) => { }), the originalResult if the result of demo(). How can define the after() function?